# Get the PID for a process started by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unix

I started a java program in debug mode in eclipse and now I need the PID of its process in order to generate a Jmap snapshot. I tried with:

```
ps aux | grep 'eclipse'
ps aux | grep 'myServerName'
```

but no chance to find that PID.

Comment: Find eclipse's pid, then filter the process list by ppid equal to that pid ?

Comment: You can say `ps aux | less` and browse through the contents. Then, when you find the process you are looking for, you may be able to the get pattern. Also, @SamuelPeter 's suggestion seems very useful to reduce the amount of lines to check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you have `java/bin` in your `path` then you can use java ps tool: 
`jps -l`

`Output:
17623 com.intellij.idea.Main
29003 sun.tools.jps.Jps`

The first column is process id.

Comment: It worked for me and it is a very simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yea this command presented much more cleaner output than "ps aux | grep java"

Answer (score 1):

Try `ps aux | grep java`, using 'java' as filter should show it.

Answer (score 0):

This is now directly supported by Eclipse (4.23, Feb. 2022, 6 years later)

> ### [Process ID in Debugger](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/platform.php#process-pid)
>
> Eclipse Debug framework can now show process ID (pid) of started processes.
>
> The pid is shown (if supported by the concrete debugger implementation) in the Console view description and properties page for the process.
>
> [image: Process properties page shows process ID -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/process_properties.png]
>
> This should work out of the box for all processes using or extending `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.RuntimeProcess`, and can be easily added to other processes by specifying `IProcess.ATTR_PROCESS_ID` process attribute.
>
> Additionally to that, Java debugger shows now process ID for the process element in the Debug view.
>
> [image: Debugger shows process ID -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.23/images/show_pid.png]